# Why does Chrome still use prefix for animations?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, vendor-prefix

I'm really not sure if this question should be here, if not, please forgive me, but I'm intrigued in the reason why Chrome/Safari still prefix **CSS3 animations**, given that any other major browser supports them as standart, some even since a long time. (IE +9, Firefox +15, Opera +12.0 according to [**this**](http://shouldiprefix.com/))

```
@keyframes anim{}
@-webkit-keyframes anim{}

div{
    animation:anim;
    -webkit-animation:anim;
}
```

Is it still considered an experimental technology?

Thanks!

Comment: IE only supported animations since version 10, but still it did so unprefixed. It only had `-ms-` prefixes during prerelease time. Firefox was since version 16.

Comment: @BoltClock Hahaha I was hoping for a more insightful response but It seems like nobody actually knows why :)